# Is IKEv2 remote access VPN possible to an ASA 5510 without Cisco AnyConnect as the client?

Tags: vpn, cisco-asa, linux, ike

I'm trying to configure a remote acccess vpn into a cisco ASA 5510 (9.1(7)15).  I want to be able to use IKEv2 with Certificate + user/password xauth with strongswan as the client under Ubuntu.

I have this working for an IKEv1 tunnel after much frustration, but I cannot get an IKEv2 configuration to work.

ipsec.conf:

```
version 2
config setup
        strictcrlpolicy=no
        charondebug="ike 4, knl 2, cfg 2"

conn %default
        ikelifetime=1440m
        keylife=60m
        rekeymargin=3m
        keyingtries=1
        ike=aes256-sha1-modp1536     #Phase1 parameters
        esp=aes256-sha1              #Phase2 parameters
        xauth=client              #Xauth client mode
        xauth_identity=chris      #identity for Xauth
        auto=add

conn "cert2"
        keyexchange=ikev2
        authby=xauthrsasig
        aggressive=no
        leftsourceip=%config
        leftauth2=xauth
        leftcert=chris2.cer
        right = vpn.my.company.com
        rightid=%any
        rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
```

From the logs on the ASA it looks like it wants to treate the IKE2 connection as a L2L tunnel.   It wants to match the DefaultL2LGroup and if I remove the %config from leftsourceip, the tunnel will come up, but shows to be a L2L tunnel and doesn't work since I dont get a DHCP address.

```
2017-04-20T16:52:59-05:00 5510a : %ASA-7-711001: IKEv2-PLAT-2: attempting to find tunnel group for IP: 72.48.127.151
2017-04-20T16:52:59-05:00 5510a : %ASA-7-711001: IKEv2-PLAT-2: ignoring tunnel-group-map default group, not L2L
2017-04-20T16:52:59-05:00 5510a : %ASA-7-711001: IKEv2-PLAT-2: mapped to DefaultL2LGroup
2017-04-20T16:52:59-05:00 5510a : %ASA-7-711001: IKEv2-PLAT-2: tg_name set to: DefaultL2LGroup
2017-04-20T16:52:59-05:00 5510a : %ASA-7-711001: IKEv2-PLAT-2: tunn grp type set to: L2L

2017-04-20T16:52:59-05:00 5510a : %ASA-7-711001: IKEv2-PLAT-1: (82): Process request attribute: Unable to get webvpn session
2017-04-20T16:52:59-05:00 5510a : %ASA-7-711001: IKEv2-PLAT-1: Error processing config mode request attibute: 1
2017-04-20T16:52:59-05:00 5510a : %ASA-7-711001: IKEv2-PLAT-1: Failed to build config mode reply
2017-04-20T16:52:59-05:00 5510a : %ASA-7-711001: IKEv2-PROTO-2: (82): Error in retrieving config mode data to send
```

I feel like there's something very obvious that I must not understand about strongswan and/or the ASA ikev2 config.